# how to create onclick event for dynamically generated buttons

Tags: c#

this is how i was generating buttons and on click event for the buttons.but every time on button click its taking the max value rather than the button clicked

```
       int noofquestions = 100;
        int k = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= noofquestions / 5; i++)
        {
            HtmlTableRow tRow = new HtmlTableRow();
            //TableRow tRow = new TableRow();          
            myTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
            for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                HtmlTableCell tCell = new HtmlTableCell();            
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                Button link = new Button();
                //LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
                link.ID = "link" + k;
                link.Text = k.ToString();
                tCell.Controls.Add(link);
                ViewState["qno"] = k;

                link.Click += new EventHandler(link_Click);
                tCell.Controls.Add(link);

                //link.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn_click);

                k = k + 1;
            }
        }



        void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: As this question contains sample code specific to a UI toolkit, please specify the UI toolkit you are using in the tags.

Comment: "its taking the max value" - can you clarify what you mean by that? Currently, your `link_Click` method does not do anything; I presume it is supposed to do more or less the same for each button, but always based on the current `k` value for the respective button? If this is true, can you add a (trivial) example implementation of `link_Click` that indicates this, please?

Comment: this is a horribly asked question.. -1

Comment: You posted your code in between some changes (e.g. changing `LinkButton` to `Button`). It won't even compile now. Please put some more effort in making your question readable.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to how you read value.

I think my meaning max value you are questioning that when you read ViewState["qno"] it is max value because it is what it set to that.

In stead of that just try to read from some other property.

```
void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //If you do ViewState["qno"] it will be max value of K instead do following thing.  
}
```

// Do following update

```
    int noofquestions = 100;
    int k = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= noofquestions / 5; i++)
    {
        HtmlTableRow tRow = new HtmlTableRow();
        //TableRow tRow = new TableRow();          
        myTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            HtmlTableCell tCell = new HtmlTableCell();            
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            Button link = new Button();
            //LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
            link.ID = "link" + k;
            link.Text = k.ToString();
            tCell.Controls.Add(link);
            ViewState[link.ID] = k;

            link.Click += new EventHandler(link_Click);
            tCell.Controls.Add(link);

            //link.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn_click);

            k = k + 1;
        }
    }



    void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Button b = (sender)Button;
        string value = ViewState[b.ID].ToString();
}
```

Comment: This code also won't compile. Why not just wait a bit till OP clarifies what they are really asking for?